# libgdx - ClickListener not affected by actor scale?

Tags: libgdx, sprite, actor, clicklistener

Here's a constructor for a card class I was making.  When I create one that is scaled and click on it, only clicks within the 1.0x scaled area are actually registered.  i.e. if I pass in 1.5 for the scale, clicks on the borders don't work.  Why not?  I've scaled the actor itself.

```
public Card(float x, float y, float scale)
{
    this.setPosition(x, y);

    faceSprite = new Sprite(MyResources.getInstance().cardTextureRegion);
    faceSprite.setPosition(x, y);
    faceSprite.setScale(scale);

    borderSprite = new Sprite(MyResources.getInstance().cardBorderTextureRegion);
    borderSprite.setPosition(x, y);
    borderSprite.setScale(scale);

    // Set boundaries for ourselves (the actor).  Note that we have to match the scale of the sprites.
    setSize(borderSprite.getWidth(), borderSprite.getHeight());
    setScale(scale);

    // Add ClickListener
    final Card thisCard = this;
    addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            ((MyStage)(thisCard.getStage())).cardClicked(thisCard);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic `Actor` class might be missing some functionalities, including proper scale handling. If all you want is displaying some images (judging by the `Sprite` objects you use), I'd suggest using the existing classes rather than making custom actors - especially since you might have trouble rendering `Sprites` with exact `Actor` parameters if you use a lot of custom actions.

`Image` allows you to display "sprites" - although somewhat simplified, it should be enough. To store the images, you can use a `Table` (more flexible) or a `Stack` (will work with multiple images of the same size).

If you really want to stick with the custom actor approach, try this instead of changing the scale:

```
setSize(borderSprite.getWidth() * scale, borderSprite.getHeight() * scale);
```

If you don't change `Card` scale manually in runtime (only set it up during creation), it should just work.

Comment: Thanks -- Mostly I was trying to figure out why the Actor wasn't behaving how I expected.  I actually had put in the setSize() version that you suggested but it felt like a hack.
What do you mean when you say "you might have trouble rendering Sprites with exact Actor parameters if you use a lot of custom actions?"

Comment: `Sprite` is not a part of `Scene2D` API. You would basically have to override every `Actor` setter with rotation, origin, etc. and call `Sprite` methods as well. Or update `Sprite` state on each render according to current `Actor` status. If you'd add a rotation or movement action, for example, `Sprite` would ignore `Actor` parameters unless you'd update them yourself manually. This is a lot of extra work for something that is already implemented - just use `Image` class to display and manage an image on `Stage`. If you need to display multiple textures as one, use one of `Group` extensions.

Comment: Okay -- still new to libgdx but I think I see what you're saying.  That didn't occur to me as a problem as right now the only use I have for my Card class being an actor at all is so that it can be clicked.  Later I'll surely use some of the actual actions and I'd have found out what you're saying the hard way.
Thanks also for the Group reference.  In general I had initially thought Sprites might be the better option as it'd give me more control, but one of the few reasons I'd need "more control" would be for stacking textures, which I should've know was supported elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use image Class to display Images.

```
Texture texture=new Texture("test.jpg");
Image image=new Image(texture);
```

//you can use setsize() or setBounds() as per your requirement.

```
image.setScale(scale);

image.addListener(new ClickListener(){
     @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

     ((MyStage)(thisCard.getStage())).cardClicked(event.getTarget());
     } 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was aware of the Image class but was planning to extend my Card actor to do more than just the Image functionality.  It still may be the way to go in the end, but I want to understand why the Actor isn't working the way I expect.